# Degree of a Smooth Map Example

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $$T^2=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2:|z|=|w|=1\}$$ denote the 2-torus. I'm trying to compute the degree of the smooth map $f:T^2\longrightarrow T^2$ given by $f(z,w)=(z^2,w^2)$. I'd like to find this degree without using algebraic topology, so I'm attempting to compute the sum
$$\operatorname{deg}(f)=\sum_{p\in f^{-1}(q)}\operatorname{sgn}(\det df_p)$$
where $q\in T^2$ is any regular value of $f$ (which is guaranteed to exist by Sard's theorem).

Is there any way that I can compute the above sum without resorting to finding the (real) coordinate representation of $f$? Since $f$ has a nice description in terms of $z$ and $w$, my immediate instinct is to work with complex coordinates. However, I'm unable to see a way to reconcile the use of these coordinates with the answer I'd get by computing $\operatorname{deg}(f)$ with real coordinate charts (and this seems particularly complicated).

Is there possibly another way to compute this, without using coordinates? I'm self-studying/revising my understanding of smooth manifolds, and I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: One way to do this is to realize the map as the restriction of a map $\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^2$. Since this is a holomorphic map the derivative is necessarily orientation preserving so all of the relevant $\mathrm{sign} (\det(df))$'s are 1.

Comment: This is great - thank you! Do you happen to have a reference/know where this is proved? I can certainly see this for maps $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, but I’m not sure how to proceed for higher dimensions.

Comment: I don't understand the issue here. You can compute the degree of the squaring map $S^1\to S^1$ (every value is a regular value); and you can easily compute the degree of a product map $f\times g\colon X\times Y\to X\times Y$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you for your comment; could you please elaborate on how to compute the degree of the product map (assuming we know the degrees of each factor, which I’m able to compute)?

Comment: Think about the form of $d(f\times g)_{(x,y)}$ (working in a product chart if you actually want a matrix).

Comment: @TedShifrin: thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose product charts for $S^1\times S^1=T^2$ (say, using angle coordinates), and working locally, write $f(\theta,\varphi)=(g(\theta),h(\varphi))$. We have
$$df_{(\theta,\varphi)}=\begin{pmatrix}dg_\theta & 0\\ 0 & dh_\varphi\end{pmatrix},$$
which is a block matrix with determinant $\det df_{(\theta,\varphi)}=(\det dg_\theta)\cdot(\det dh_\varphi).$

This gives (for $q$ regular)

$$\sum_{p\in f^{-1}(q)}\operatorname{sgn}\det df_p=\sum_{(\theta,\varphi)\in f^{-1}(q)}\operatorname{sgn}(\det dg_\theta\cdot\det dh_\varphi),$$
allowing us to relate $\deg f$ to the degrees of both $g,h:S^1\longrightarrow S^1$. It can be shown that $\deg g=\deg h=2$, and since there are $2\cdot 2=4$ elements in $f^{-1}(q)$, the above sum becomes $1+1+1+1=4$.